# How much time should I give/commit to an employer

Tags: professionalism, ethics

I was hired last June, and so far I've learned a lot overall, although not as much as I expected to; mostly due to the size of the department, when I joined we were 4 and now we're only 2 doing all the work (DBA, Software Development, Support, Network, and even Phoneline maintenance which I know little to nothing) most of the non-Software stuff has been learned on the go which can make it very difficult the first couple of times done.

When I was hired I was asked directly by the owner to get very familiar with a particular SDK, which I have and it has not been easy considering I was thrown into the support role the first day I got here (I think my supervisor and the owner didn't have too much communication) But now it seems the SDK disinterests him, and he is now more focused into reports and their optimization. So now I'm struggling keeping up with all the work I'm doing plus learning how to use reporting services efficiently. I've been having a hard time keeping up with all the things I have to learn(I graduated as a computer engineer, hardware track. So I only have the core programming courses backing me up) When I was hired I clearly expressed this and they showed no concern, they just told me to try really hard. And I have, but the way the organization works doesn't fulfill me professionally.

It might just be me getting overwhelmed, this is my first professional job. And I'd hate to leave just cause I couldn't do the job. But the load is just exhausting, as a department we have expressed our concerns and other than noted nothing has been done about them.

But in the case I end up deciding terminating my relationship with this company, is it okay if I just give a full year of service? Should I stay? Should I leave right away? It's the first time I encounter a situation like this.

Comment: I think you should focus your question on dealing with the frustration as a new developer thrown into this situation and not whether you should keep this job or not. Hate to say it, but you could very easily end up in a similar situation with your next job. There are no guarantees and things change all the time in business.

Comment: You ask "how much time" in your question heading. I guess you mean time as in "one year". But how much time do you spend in the office, i.e.. what is your schedule like? Could this be what is exhausting you?

Comment: I mean time of services given to a company, and the schedule at the office doesn't really bother me @Brandin

Comment: Ultimately no job is fulfilling. As you are young, you'll likely believe your work is ultimately what defines you but as you get older you'll realize there are other more important things. Nobody is going to remember "Just Do It" who learned some new programming method just as you are not going to remember today. You'll remember being young, and you'll laugh at what you worried about. Truth is you shouldn't job hunt because you're unhappy but rather you should job hunt because you want to experience new things after this which may ultimately make you try other things.

Comment: The only fulfilling job is when you're self employed

Comment: @Kilisi, I don't find that to be true, the worst job I ever had was being self-employed, I have no desire to market or do accounting (or even review the accounting someone else does). It isn't for everyone or even the majority of people. The most fulfilling job I had was teaching, but the pay was less than optimal.

Comment: true enough, my comment was miles off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always be on the lookout for a better job, but in the mean time, you should stick with it. Perseverance and learning new things are two major qualities for a developer. There will always be tasks you don't like to do. Some jobs require you to spend more time on them then others.

It's hard to believe at this time, but you will get better at these things if you're willing to put some time into them. You never know when these new skills will benefit you in the future. Many jobs are a large mix of different skills and technologies that change all time with little warning. You won't like all of them. Staff turnovers can cause you to pick up the slack on things you don't like.

I'm not saying you have to suffer indefinitely. Life is too short for that. You've been thrown into these things and that makes it tougher, but if you keep at it and have a plan for consistent improvement, it will become more tolerable and you'll be a better programmer who will be better prepared for the next opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

You are only responsible for fulfilling your contract.  If your employment does not have a contractual end date, then you are only responsible for providing reasonable notice that you are leaving (as per local custom).  A one year at your first placement is unlikely to raise flags as job hopping.  As a matter of practicality it is usually better to find your next placement before putting in notice for the current one.